# Cannot load Rails.config.active_storage.service

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, rails-activestorage, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I'm setting up a new rails 5.2 app utilising Active Storage and using AWS for the hosting of images in production.

However, I'm having an issue with the app reading the credentials:

```
2018-07-06T08:11:52.625415+00:00 app[web.1]: ! Unable to load application: Aws::Sigv4::Errors::MissingCredentialsError: Cannot load `Rails.config.active_storage.service`:
2018-07-06T08:11:52.625432+00:00 app[web.1]: missing credentials, provide credentials with one of the following options:
2018-07-06T08:11:52.625435+00:00 app[web.1]:   - :access_key_id and :secret_access_key
2018-07-06T08:11:52.625437+00:00 app[web.1]:   - :credentials
2018-07-06T08:11:52.625479+00:00 app[web.1]:   - :credentials_provider
```

This is an existing S3 Bucket which I created a new user just for this app. I'm happy with the CORS etc.

The user is set up under the S3FullAccess group.

I've edited the credentials in my app via `$EDITOR="atom --wait" rails credentials:edit`

The contents of the file:

```
aws:
  access_key_id: [my access key]
  secret_access_key: [my secrect key]

# Used as the base secret for all MessageVerifiers in Rails, including the one protecting cookies.
secret_key_base: [my secret key base]
```

Appreciate this is in YAML format, I have played with using one space, and one tab on the keys, but this doesn't seem to make a difference.

When I save and close the file, the terminal writes `New credentials encrypted and saved.`

I also have `gem 'aws-sdk-s3', '~>1', require: false` installed.

And config/storage.yml

```
test:
  service: Disk
  root: <%= Rails.root.join("tmp/storage") %>

local:
  service: Disk
  root: <%= Rails.root.join("storage") %>

# Use rails credentials:edit to set the AWS secrets (as aws:access_key_id|secret_access_key)
amazon:
  service: S3
  access_key_id: <%= Rails.application.credentials.dig(:aws, :access_key_id) %>
  secret_access_key: <%= Rails.application.credentials.dig(:aws, :secret_access_key) %>
  region: eu-west-2
  bucket: [mybucket]
```

Any suggestions on what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Try `gem 'aws-sdk', '~> 3'`, or just `gem 'aws-sdk'`

Comment: It's not the gem.  Tried `gem 'aws-sdk'`.

Comment: Can you share `config/storage.yml`?

Comment: @GeorgeClaghorn added to post

Comment: `missing credentials` → I'm sure you did, but anyway, did you test `aws` connection with a Ruby script?

Comment: @iGian yeah I've tried it with a number of different users set up in AWS.

Comment: The whole "aws-sdk" is not needed this is enough `gem "aws-sdk-s3", require: false`

Answer (score 14):

I think you're missing the `master.key` file in your server. Check your local repo in `config/master.key` (this file is added to your `.gitignore` by default).
Add this file to your server or set `ENV["RAILS_MASTER_KEY"]`.

Comment: Thanks! @OctaviaTogami

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me on Heroku: in "Settings > Config vars" add a `RAILS_MASTER_KEY` key, with the content of your your `config/master.key` file (from your Rails app) as the value.

Comment: Thank you! I just got stung by this. Quick tip for anyone else, try: `heroku config:set RAILS_MASTER_KEY=$(echo ./config/credentials/production.key)`

Answer (score 4):

Go into `config/environments/development.rb` and make sure you have this:

`config.active_storage.service = :local`

in `config/environments/production` you should have

`config.active_storage.service = :amazon`

`amazon` is for Amazon S3. It can be changed to whichever storage service you want to use. See the Rails docs for more info on storage services and Active Storage.

Answer (score 2):

In Rails 5.2, do the following:

Step 1. In `config/storage.yml` add

```
amazon:
  service: S3
  access_key_id: <%= ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'] %>
  secret_access_key: <%= ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'] %>
  region: ap-south-1
  bucket: my-bucket
```

Step 2:

```
Copy config/credentials.yml.example to config/credentials.yml
```

and add the following in `config/credentials.yml`

```
  development:
    AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: YOUR-KEY
    AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: YOUR-SECRET
```

`credentials.yml` is already added to `.gitignore` by default.

Step 3:

In `application.rb`

Uncomment the following:

```
# Load ENV variables from credentials.yml file
config.before_configuration do
  env_file = File.join(Rails.root, 'config', 'credentials.yml')
  YAML.load(File.open(env_file))[Rails.env].each do |key, value|
    ENV[key.to_s] = value
  end if File.exists?(env_file)
end
```

Restart the server and try to upload again.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error. In my case the problem was neither with configs, nor with `master.key`. Starting `Redis server` fixed the error. For MacOS:

```
$> redis-server
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way of solving this issue (worked for me)
Run **rake secret** in the console
copy the key
go to config and open application.rb
inside the class type: **config.secret_key_base = "paste the output of rake secrete"**